# I am getting error while executing ng update -g @angular/cli

Tags: angular, npm

While executing `ng update -g @angular/cli`

I am getting following error :

> An unexpected error happened; package amcharts3-angular2 has no version
>   null while executing ng update -g @angular/cli command.

Comment: Could you provide more information on your issue?

Comment: Which version of Angular were you using prior to attempting to update?  It seems [amcharts has different installation processes](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts3-angular2#installation) depending on which Angular version is being run, which may be complicating your upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing this problem in another package, problem occurs due to not mention version detail in package.json file.
Solution: Mention valid version number in Package.json file dependency section like this

```
amcharts/amcharts3-angular:^1.5.0
```

then

```
ng update -g @angular/cli
```